# Spring Cloud Configuration Client not refreshing properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a configuration server and a Spring Boot 2.3.1 application connects to the server to load the configuration properties for the proper profile.

The configuration server uses git to get the configuration files for each application and profile.

This works alright and when the Spring Boot application start it loads from the configuration server the correct values for the properties.

When I update a value in a configuration file and push it to git and then do a `Post` to `/actuator/refresh` endpoint of the Spring Boot application, I see a json returned with the names of the properties I updated which is what I would expect.

The problem is that the properties are not actually updated after that. They remain with the old value.

For example:

```
@Service
//@RefreshScope
public class WhitelistService {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WhitelistService.class);

  private final WhitelistRepository whitelistRepository;
  private final Boolean isWhitelistEnabled;
  private final Integer identifier;

  @Autowired
  public WhitelistService(WhitelistRepository whitelistRepository,
        @Value("${app.whitelist.isEnabled:true}") Boolean isWhitelistEnabled,
        @Value("${app.whitelist.identifier:-1}") Integer identifier) {
    super();
    this.whitelistRepository = whitelistRepository;
    this.isWhitelistEnabled = isWhitelistEnabled;
    this.identifier = identifier;
  }

  public boolean processBasedOnWhitelist(Long id) {
    if (!isWhitelistEnabled)
        return true;
    else if (identifier <= -1)
        return isInWhitelist(id);
    else
        return isInWhitelistWithIdentifier(id, identifier);
  }

 }
```

If the `@RefreshScope` is commented out as above and I update the `app.whitelist.isEnabled` in the proper property file and push it to the configuration file and do a `actuator/refresh` then the `app.whitelist.isEnabled` remains with the old value.

This is true even I use a `setter` for the value field or just annotate the field itself with `@Value` during its declaration.

If I enable `@RefreshScope` the value is updated as expected.

However, last time I used the Configuration Server and Spring Boot as a client, in another project, this was not the case (unless this changed in Spring Boot 2.3.1). It used to update immediately without the need of having `@RefreshScope`.

Am I missing something? I would like to avoid adding another annotation to every Bean I have a property value reference. It is not a big deal but it seems unnecessary and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

At Spring Cloud Bus documentation: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-bus/2.1.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-bus.html#_bus_refresh_endpoint

> The /actuator/bus-refresh endpoint clears the RefreshScope cache and rebinds @ConfigurationProperties. See the Refresh Scope documentation for more information.

So either you have your bean annotated with @RefreshScope or it has the annotation of @ConfigurationProperties. As your bean is not annotated with @ConfigurationProperties, it has to use the @RefreshScope annotation in order to refresh it.

Probably, in your other project, your bean would be annotated with @ConfigurationProperties

Comment: Has this changed from Spring Boot 1.x? Because in the other project I surely did not have any annotation except for `@Component` or `@Service` in my classes

Comment: Jordi is correct. You either need `@RefreshScope` or use `@ConfigurationProperties`.